# Attoparsec /= version of stringCI

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm parsing robots.txt files and I've written the parser to successfully parse a "well-formed" robots.txt file. I've been able to adjust the parser to skip lines that start with a symbol (like # or / for comments) but only using `inClass "#/"`.

One problem I've been unable to solve is skipping a line if it DOES NOT contain the string I want to match.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /misc/
Disallow: /modules/
Doesn't belong here
Disallow: /profiles/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /themes/
```

I first tried matching using:

`satisfy (notInClass "DdUu") *> skipWhile (not . isEndOfLine)`

And figured doing it that way would negate my need for the specific comment line parser as the hashes or slashes don't fall into the character class. The problem is that this doesn't work.

I also realize it wouldn't work ANYWAY if it did, because it wouldn't solve matching for something like "Disallow" vs. "Don't allow".

Here's the parsing code (without the comment skipping code, this only works for well-formed robots.txt):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, RankNTypes #-}

import           Prelude hiding (takeWhile)
import           Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import           Data.Char
import           Data.Text as T hiding (toLower)
import           Data.Text.Encoding as E
import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Attoparsec.ByteString
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as AC
import           Data.Array.Unboxed
import           Data.ByteString as B hiding (takeWhile)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BI
import           Data.Word (Word8)

type RuleMap = [(ByteString, ByteString)]

-- newtype for indexable ua
newtype UserAgent = UserAgent { unUA :: ByteString }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data RuleSet = RuleSet
    { userAgent :: UserAgent,
      rules     :: RuleMap }
     deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

main = do
    r <- B.readFile "/Users/ixmatus/Desktop/robots.txt"
    print $ parse (many1 parseUABlock) r

stripper = E.encodeUtf8 . T.strip . E.decodeUtf8

isNotEnd = not . AC.isEndOfLine

-- | Catch all character matching, basically
matchALL :: Word8 -> Bool
matchALL = inClass ":/?#[]@!$&'()*%+,;=.~a-zA-Z0-9 _-"

-- | @doParse@ Run the parser, complete the partial if the end of the stream has
-- a newline with an empty string
doParse :: ByteString -> [RuleSet]
doParse cont =
    case parse (many1 parseUABlock) cont of
        Done _ set -> set
        Partial f -> handlePartial (f B.empty)
        Fail {} -> []

-- | @handlePartial@ Handle a partial with empty string by simply
-- returning the last completion
handlePartial :: forall t a. IResult t [a] -> [a]
handlePartial (Done _ r) = r
handlePartial (Fail {})  = []

-- | @parseUABlock@ Parse a user-agent and rules block
parseUABlock = do
    ua    <- parseUACol *> uA
    rulez <- many1 parseRules

    return RuleSet { userAgent = UserAgent ua,
                     rules = rulez }

-- | @matchUACol@ Parse the UA column and value taking into account
-- possible whitespace craziness
parseUACol = AC.skipSpace
          *> AC.stringCI "User-Agent"
          <* AC.skipSpace
          *> AC.char8 ':'
          *> AC.skipSpace

uA = do
    u <- takeWhile1 isNotEnd
    return (stripper u)

-- | @parseRules@ Parse the directives row
parseRules = (,) <$> parseTransLower
             <*> directiveRule

directiveRule = do
    rule <- takeWhile1 matchALL <* many1 AC.endOfLine

    return (stripper rule)

parseTransLower = do
    res <- parseDirectives <* AC.skipSpace
    return (lowercase res)

ctypeLower = listArray (0,255) (Prelude.map (BI.c2w . toLower) ['\0'..'\255']) :: UArray Word8 Word8
lowercase = B.map (\x -> ctypeLower!x)

directives = AC.stringCI "Disallow" <|> AC.stringCI "Allow"

-- | @parseDirectives@ Parse the directive column and any possibly
-- funny whitespace
parseDirectives = AC.skipSpace
                  *> directives -- <|> AC.stringCI "Crawl-delay" <|> AC.stringCI "Sitemap")
                  <* AC.skipSpace
                  <* AC.char8 ':'
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach.

Define:

```
data RobotsDirective = RobotsDirective String String
```

This represents a parsed directive in a robots.txt file. The first string is the directive (i.e. `UserAgent`, `Allow`, `Disallow`, etc.) and the second string is the stuff after the colon.

Now write a parser for a `RobotsDirective`:

```
parseRD :: Parser RobotsDirective
```

`parseRD` will look for a directive name (which should only contain letters, digits and dashes and maybe underscores) followed by a colon followed by zero or more non-newline characters. Ignore white space as appropriate. If `parseRD` finds such a pattern it will create and return a `RobotsDirective`. Otherwise it will skip over one line of characters and try again.

Now that you have a parser for a `RobotsDirective`, you can create a parser for `[RobotsDirective]` in the standard way.

This parser simply skips over any line which doesn't look like a directive and this will include blank lines, comment lines and lines that begin with `Don't allow...`. However, it can return a `RobotsDirective` for lines which are not valid in a robots.txt file, i.e.:

```
foo: blah
```

will return `RobotsDirective "foo" "blah"`. After you have parsed a robots.txt file and have  gotten a list of `RobotsDirective` values, simply go through that list and ignore the ones you are not interested in.

Comment: I've already done that; what does need to happen is I have to skip out any lines that don't match the specific strings so my assumption there is that I can skip additional/non-standard directives as a result too. I've already wrote a `/=` version of `stringCI` and am trying to get it just right. We'll see.

Comment: The other problem with your approach is that the the directives need to be grouped by the User-agent header as they are done that way "positionally" in the robots.txt file (I think it's stupid, but that's how everyone - google/bing/etc... - is handling them). So I have the *RuleSet* and *RuleMap* types to make walking that easy.

Comment: What I am saying is that you should only use attoparsec to parse the basic structure of the robots.txt file. Once you have a `[RobotsDirective]` it will be easy to: 1) ignore directives which don't make sense and 2) rearrange the directives however you like.

Comment: I understand and I've even tried it; but I keep feeling like it's inefficient to do all the parsing then to discard what I don't want from the parsed result. Am I thinking about it wrong? If I have to skip nonsense data in the file anyway, it seems to make sense that I should also skip directives I don't want? (using a white-listing approach skips anything that doesn't match what I want)

Comment: First answer: don't worry about it. After all, how big are robots.txt files? Second answer: Haskell's laziness means that list operations rarely create separate lists. For example, `take 10 [1..1000000]` doesn't first create a list of a million elements and then take the first 10. The  elements of `[1..1000000]` are generated on demand. Third answer: Haskell can in cases can combine list operations to eliminate intermediate results: `map (+1) . map (*2) xs` effectively runs as if you had written `map (\x->2*x+1) xs`. ...

Comment: Fourth answer: Consider a more generalize robots.txt parser which identified each line as either a 1) directive, 2) a comment / blank line or 3) a junk line (neither 1 or 2). Such a parser could be used not only for extracting information from the file but also for rewriting the file while preserving comments and junk lines, and any application which used a robots.txt file could use this parser as a starting point. Yes, it performs more work, but it would also be the "robots.txt parser to end all robots.txt parsers" and you'll never have to write another robots.txt parser ever again.